# change color of matches that start with # in string Js or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working in a string in php

```
$string="Hello #today is #Sunday #everywhere";
```

where with ths function (PHP) I replace the colors of the hashtahgs matches in the string.

```
function hashtag_color($string) {
  return preg_replace('/#(\w+)/', "<span class=OrangeColor>#$1</span>", $string);
}
```

What I want is to do the same but in `JQuery` or `JS`. Because I am editing the output string with `àjax` and the `succcess: function(data){}` returns plain text which need to be coloured again.

Comment: Okay, and what is your question? (In other words, where is the JS code that you have an issue with, and what is that issue, exactly?)

Comment: It is basically the same code, just use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method.

Comment: thanks you mean something like this? `var string = data.replace(/#(\w+)/g, '<span class=Orange>$1</span>');`

Comment: @Max have you checked my answer?

Comment: I am testing it. thanks you.

Comment: I'd use `var string = data.replace(/#\w+/g, '<span class="OrangeColor">$&</span>');`

Comment: what would be the difference between this one and the proposed below?

Comment: by testing, this script colours `#today!!` all of it including the exclamation marks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/#\w*/g` regex to found all the words starting with `#` from a string.

Please check working snippet

```js
var mainString = "Hello #today is #Sunday #everywhere";
r = /#\w*/g; // big letter with word symbols, global search
function f(x){
  return '<span class="OrangeColor">'+x+'</span>' // rewrited
}
h = mainString.replace(r,f); //replace
$("#mainString").html(h); //set
```

```css
.OrangeColor {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="mainString"></p>
```

Comment: It works good. thanks you.